# Generic to transform array of string variables to union type

Tags: typescript

```
const A= "Hello"
const B= "Bye"
const C="Foo"

const myArrayOfConstants=[A,B,C]
```

`type ConvertArrayToUnion<myArrayOfConstants>` ==> Expected type output: `"Hello" | "Bye" | "Foo".`

I tried with

```
type ConvertArrayToUnion<T extends readonly string[]>= T[number]
```

But in this case I am not passing an array of strings, but the variable name of each constant (which I guess it is a tupple?) so it doesn't work.

Comment: you are right possibly, how it would be in this case?

Comment: A variable is not a type. For TypeScript to be able to correctly infer a type from a tuple, you have to define that tuple with a `const` assertion. Then it just becomes a matter of using `type X = ConvertArrayToUnion<typeof myArrayOfConstants>`.

Comment: You are right @RobbyCornelissen. My generic function worked once added as const with typeof. I tried before with typeof but didn't work because it also needed as const. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
const A= "Hello"
const B= "Bye"
const C="Foo"

const myArrayOfConstants=[A,B,C] as const;

type test = typeof myArrayOfConstants[number]
```

Comment: Thanks but I need the generic function, not this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as const` and `typeof`

```
const A= "Hello";
const B= "Bye";
const C= "Foo";

const myArrayOfConstants = [A, B, C] as const;
type MyType = typeof myArrayOfConstants[number]; // "Hello" | "Bye" | "Foo"
```

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned, I need the generic for this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
const convert = myArrayOfConstants as const;

// type UnionType = "Hello" | "Bye" | "Foo"
type UnionType = typeof convert[number];
```

hope it can help